# How do I visualize a dataset of images to obtain the best kernel for SVM?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

With a two dimensional data set we can plot in on plane and check which kernel to apply in the SVM, but how do i decide the kernel if i want to classify the images with the help of SVM?I there any method which can help me to visualize the data (multi-feature)?

Comment: No - you'd train models with different kernels and see which performs best.

Comment: @Tchotchk Thanks for the help